# Multiple :value in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this that takes the value and send it to my backend along with others in a form

```html
<select 
    v-model="formData.account_bank" 
    id="branch" 
    @change="getbranch"
>
  <option v-for="bank in selectBank" :key="bank.id" :value="bank.code">{{ 
      bank.name
  }}</option>
</select>
```

but before it is sent I need to get some data to populate a second selectbox using `bank.id` which I should have as `:value = "bank.id"` in the code above.

To get the value to make the api call that populates the second selectbox I just do

```js
var branch = document.getElementById('branch').value;
```

and use it in the API call.

But here I need to get the `bank.id` to make the first api call that populates the selectbox and still have the `bank.code` there as form data to submit.

I have thought about getting the `key` using javascript which has the `bank.id`. But can not figure how or a different way it should work.

Comment: You could bind a data attribute? `:data-bank-id="bank.id"`

Comment: Can you update the question to show what you've described? The most effective solution might depend on how the second `select` ties into the form data and submission method.

Comment: @Daniel_Knights That is exactly what i was looking for. Added that and then got the attribute of the selected option.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this problem is to bind the entire `bank` object to your `<select>` model.

Then you can use its `id` to populate your other select options and its `code` to construct your form data payload.

For example

```html
<select 
  v-model="selectedBank" 
  id="branch" 
  @change="getbranch"
>
  <option v-for="bank in selectBank" :key="bank.id" :value="bank">{{ 
      bank.name
  }}</option>
</select>
```

```js
data: () => ({
  formData: {
    // whatever you originally had here
  },
  selectedBank: {} // empty object or perhaps a default bank
}),
methods: {
  getBranch () {
    const bankId = this.selectedBank.id
    // make API call, etc
  },
  submitForm () {
    // build form data
    const formData = {
      ...this.formData,
      account_bank: this.selectedBank.code
    }

    // submit form, etc
  }
}
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Value-Bindings